# clear stack when navigating to nested stack navigator inside bottom tab navigator

Tags: react-native, expo, stack, react-navigation

## **Current Behavior**

My react-native application consists of a BottomTabNavigator that contains several StackNavigators. A simplified example of my structure looks like this

**userLoggedIn or signinSkiped ?** (

BottomTab

- Tab 1

  - Stack

    - Screen 1
    - Screen 2
- Tab 2

  - Stack

    - Screen 1
    - Screen 2

) : ( Stack

- SigninScreen
- RegisterScreen

)

## **My problem is: **

1. I log in into my application
2. I am on Screen 1 of the Tab 1.
3. From the Screen 1 of the Tab 1 i navigate to Screen 2 of the Tab 1 on the press button.
4. From the Screen 2 of the Tab 1 i navigate to Screen 2 of the Tab 2 on the press button.
5. I log out from my application
6. I am on SigninScreen
7. I click on the button "signinSkip" on the SigninScreen (signinSkiped = true)
8. I am on the Screen 1 of the Tab 1
9. I click on Tab 2
10. Screen 2 of the Tab 2 is displayed

## **Expected behavior: **

When I click on Tab 2 as described in the step 9 above, Screen 1 of the Tab 2 should be displayed and not the Screen 2.

It works as expected, if I do following steps:

1. I sign in into my application
2. I am on the Screen 1 of the Tab 1
3. I click on Tab 2 and I'm on the Screen 1 of the Tab 2
4. From the Screen 1 of the Tab 2 i navigate to Screen 2 of the Tab 2 on the press button.
5. I log out from my application
6. I am on SigninScreen
7. I click on the button "signinSkip" on the SigninScreen (signinSkiped = true)
8. I am on the Screen 1 of the Tab 1
9. I click on Tab 2
10. Screen 1 of the Tab 2 is displayed

I assume, it has to do with refreshing of stack after logging out, but I'm not sure.
i would really appreciate your help

**I tried following:**

Navigate from Screen 2 to Screen 1 of the Tab 2 if the user loggs out (within the onAuthStateChanged listener). I get the expected result, but it leads to the error: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Answer (score 1):

you can reset your navigation stack when the user logs out of your application. Doing this will keep the behavior consistent.

```
navigation.dispatch(
        CommonActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          routes: [
            {
              name: 'SigninScreen',                  
            }
          ],
        })
      );
```

To answer your question on why the SigninScreen. You have nested navigators, which means that whatever you are doing in the parent navigator (tab navigator) is not going to affect the child navigator (screen 1 and 2). The reason why you are seeing the behavior described is that the mounted screens don't get unmounted. Whatever you had in your child navigator won't be reset when the user navigate  away from it (i.e. clicking Tab 1 or tab 3 etc.)

The code above will reset all of that when the user gets to the login screen. This will remove all the mounted screens, which will make sure when the user click on Tab 2, screen 1 always gets mounted first.

Alternately, you can add a tab press listener to manually goto Screen 1 when the user press Tab 2.

```
<Tab.Screen name="Tab 2" component={Tab2}
      listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
        tabPress: (event) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          navigation.navigate(“Tab2”, {screen: “Screen1” };
        }
      })}
    />
```

Comment: Should I put your suggested code inside  onAuthStateChanged-Listener in the Screen 2 of the Tab 2 or within the signOut-Function?

Comment: you can add a screen listener for your SigninScreen screen and run this code everything the user hits this screen, or you can attach that to your signout function.

Comment: I don't understand, why in a SigninScreen?
Cause the problem what I want to solve is related to Tab 2 of the BottomTab and not to the Stack with SigninScreen and RegisterScreen.

My signout-Function is in Settings-Screen within the Tab 3 of BottomTab. 
When user signs out, the userLoggedIn-State is set to False and the user is redirected to SigninScreen, because the condition "userLoggedIn or signinSkiped" as indicated in my simplified example structure above is not met.

Comment: I just added an explanation on why. Also added an alternative solution.

Comment: Did my explanation help answer your question?

Comment: This helped me, and I confirm this code works, once the typos are corrected (you forgot a closing parenthesis and it should be event.preventDefault not e.preventDefault).
Thanks for your answer !